# Greek VAT validation number code

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there anybody which can assist me with a code in VB.NET visual studio 2010 for validating Greek TAX Registration number (VAT).

Comment: What are the rules for validation? Do you have a reference?

Comment: No thats the first issue I don't know the rules, I only know that is a 9 digit number under European laws

Comment: If it comes to it, there's a web service you can use http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl

Comment: @Rup can you assist me how to use this service?

Comment: ho1 linked to a CodeProject project that uses it, albeit in C# http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/VATchecker.aspx, or you can just right-click on your project and 'Add Service Reference' in Visual Studio to generate a class wrapper from that URL. Then you instantiate the client class generated and there should then be a 'checkVat' method on the class you can call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not EU laws that makes it 9 digits, it depends on the country.

Unfortunately I don't know if you can get hold of the algorithm anywhere and even if you could, that still wouldn't mean that it was a valid VAT number. The only way that I know of to be sure that it's a valid VAT number is to validate it against the webservice as mentioned in Rup's comment. So if you're going to use this validation to decide if you're going to charge VAT or not, I'd not trust just a calculation since then you might end up breaking the rules (and possibly having to pay VAT that you haven't collected...).

There's a code project article showing how to use it (C# but should be relatively easy to convert to VB.Net if needed): [VIES - VAT number checker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/VATchecker.aspx)

Though obviously it might be worthwhile checking for 9 digits first to rule out any obviously invalid ones.

Comment: Yes ho1 that will be the first validation i will do for it but also i need to validating against the VIES to sure that the entered number is VALID. I'll see what i can do with that "VAT number checker"

Comment: @Lefteris: If you go to the link in Tim's answer it's a list of FAQs for the VIES web service, so might be worth reading through that too.

Comment: Well there is an on-line validation web site but i want to use this validation in my vb code which implement it for windows application. Yes i knew these FAQs but they didn't help me in what i want to do it

Comment: @Lefteris: As long as your windows application can access the internet you should be able to consume the webservice from your app. The main issue will be that, as stated in one of the FAQs, if the webservice is down, you won't be able to validate until it's up again, and also that if you need to validate large amounts of VAT numbers it might be slow since you need to do them one at a time.

Comment: Well @Rup i wish to have the ability to give you more than one vote. your solution is the top in my consideration. I made the class as DLL and imported in my solution and from there i do my work. YES that is what i really want to, THANK you very much

Answer (score 2):

As it is mentioned [here](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/faqvies.do) you won't get the complete validation because *"the European Commission cannot divulge these algorithms"*. However greece Vat must have a 9 digits block. 
So it might suffice to check this with a Regex:

```
Dim text As String = Me.TxtVAT.Text
Dim regex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^\d{9}$", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled)
If regex.IsMatch(text) Then
   'do something'
Else
   'do something else'
End If
```

Comment: I thing Tim you are taking a result from comparing two text fields, if I have right on this then it is not what i'm looking for. What I'm looking is a validation for the all number if fulfil all the requirements for the VIES. I thing it will be a mathematic validation.

Answer (score 2):

I found [a JavaScript implementation of the checksum algorithm](http://www.braemoor.co.uk/software/vat.shtml) which references [this site](http://sima-pc.com/nif.php) as the original algorithm source:

```
function ELVATCheckDigit (vatnumber) {
  // Checks the check digits of a Greek VAT number.

  var total = 0;
  var multipliers = [256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2];

  //eight character numbers should be prefixed with an 0.
  if (vatnumber.length == 8) {vatnumber = "0" + vatnumber};

  // Extract the next digit and multiply by the counter.
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    total = total + Number(vatnumber.charAt(i)) * multipliers[i];

  // Establish check digit.
  total = total % 11;
  if (total > 9) {total = 0;};  

  // Compare it with the last character of the VAT number. If it is the same, 
  // then it's a valid check digit.
  if (total == vatnumber.slice (8,9)) 
    return true
  else 
    return false;
}
```

but that only checks it's in a valid format, not if the number has actually been allocated. As above, you can use the web service for that:

- right-click on your project and 'Add Service References'; enter the URL http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl and a namespace name
- instantiate a `checkVatPortTypeClient` from that namesspace
- call `client.checkVat`. You'll need to put the country code and VAT number into string variables for it to reference, and provide output variables for the validation flag, the company name and address.

Answer (score 0):

For Greek Tax Number Validation you could use https://tin-check.com/

They have a API that returns the response in JSON
https://api.tin-check.com/

May be a good solution if beside greek tax number you need to perform validation for more countries. They perform validation for more than 100 countries.